# Clearing input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JavaScript where I want to clear all of the input fields when either radio button is clicked.  (The radio buttons are for what type of policy number is inputted).  I have created a function called `Clear()` to clear all of my inputs, and I have called that function within the if statements that see which radio button is clicked. Since it doesn't matter which one is clicked, becuase all input fields are wiped when any of the two is clicked, that function call is in both.

I have looked online for help to this solution; however, what I have seems to be correct as in structure and calling of the JavaScript function.  My code is as follows:

```
if ($('#EstimatePolicyNumber').val()) {
        $('#EstimateRadio').prop('checked', true);
        $('#estimate').show();
        $('#exisiting').hide();
        Clear();
}
else if ($('#ExisitingPolicyNumber').val()){
        $('#ExisitingRadio').prop('checked', true);
        $('#existing').show();
        $('#estimate').hide();
        Clear();
}

//Used to clear all of the input fields
function Clear() {
        $('#ExisitingPolicyNumber').val('');
        $('#EstimatePolicyNumber').val('');
        $('#NewPolicyNumber').val('');
        $('#EffectiveDate').val('');
        $('#ServicingAgent').val('');
        $('#CheckBox').prop('checked', false);
}
```

Here is the html for the radio buttons

```
<label class="float-left" id="radio-1">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RCTRadioType, "EstimateRadio", new { @id = "EstimateRadio", @name = "radio", @style = "margin:5px;" })
        Estimate  Number
</label>

<div class="clear-fix"></div>

  <label class="float-left"  id="radio-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.RCTRadioType, "ExisitingRadio", new { @id = "ExisitingRadio", @name = "radio", @style = "margin:5px;" })
          Farm Family Policy Number
   </label>
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know, what *are* you doing wrong? What happens? What's supposed to happen?

Comment: when and how is the code before the function triggered?

Comment: It is very unclear. Why don't you just trigger the clear on click of a radio button instead of doing it on check/uncheck? They both seem to do the same... Also, you are checking for val() - if this is empty both of them return false, no?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: when does your `if` code run? You don't show it being in any event handling callback so it's hard to help without seeing full sequence

Comment: The if statement is ran on load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to achieve and what doesn't work.

If I understood what you are trying to do, the easiest way is to bind a click function to each radio you want to manage. Doing this way, it would make things easier to set different ids on radios, for better readability.

For instance, let's take following radio buttons:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioButton" value="1">Option 1</input>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioButton" value="2">Option 2</input>
    <input type="text" value="Click Option 2 to clear me" id="textField"/>
</form>
```

You can bind a different `click()` function to each radio, as follows:

```
$("#radio1").click(function(){
    $('#estimate').show();
    $('#exisiting').hide();
    Clear();
});

$("#radio2").click(function(){
    $('#estimate').hide();
    $('#exisiting').show();
    Clear();
});
```

This way you don't have to check against any val().

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ghaa9wu2/2/)

Comment: I've got this one to work, and does seem a little easier to read as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind each radiobutton a click event to make them take action. Just replace first part of your code like below.

```
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function () {

    if ($('#EstimatePolicyNumber').val()) {
            $('#EstimateRadio').prop('checked', true);
            $('#estimate').show();
            $('#exisiting').hide();
            Clear();
    }
    else if ($('#ExisitingPolicyNumber').val()){
            $('#ExisitingRadio').prop('checked', true);
            $('#existing').show();
            $('#estimate').hide();
            Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ($('#EstimatePolicyNumber').val() != '')`

Comment: The logic on this seems to be correct; however, when I implement it the input fields aren't cleared.

Comment: You might need to put this code in $(document).ready(function(){...});